# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version~~

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with my search engine. I can search but when clicking the link this what come out "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Pacina' at line 1"... I dont know how to fix it.Your answer might be a big help for me.. :)

This is my code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("infokiosk");

    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from  basicinfo WHERE name=$name") or die(mysql_error());

While($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$id= $_GET['id'];
$name=$_GET['name'];
$description=$_GET['description'];

{
?>
  <tr>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td><?php echo $description; ?>
</tr>




    </div>
<?php }} ?>

<br>
<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from  staffreg WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' or description LIKE '%$search%' or keyword LIKE '%$search%'") or die(mysql_error());

While($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$id= $row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$description=$row['description'];
{
?>






<tr>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
<?php echo $description; ?>
<?php echo $status; ?>
</tr>





    </div>
<?php }}?>

<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from  search WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' or description LIKE '%$search%' ") or die(mysql_error());

While($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$id= $row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$description=$row['description'];
$content=$row['content'];

{
?>






<tr>
<td><?php echo $name; ?><br> <?php echo $content ?></td>

</tr>




    </div>
<?php }}?>
```

I dont know what/where line is the problem.. :( 
thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: You probably need quotes around `$name` in this line:`"select * from  basicinfo WHERE name=$name"`, but actually you need a whole lot more as this is asking for an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: You should read on [how to prevent SQL injections in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` should be surrounded with the single quote in query,

```
"SELECT * FROM  basicinfo WHERE `name`='".$name."'";
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

for your SELECT statement you need to make $sql like

```
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from  search WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' or description LIKE '%".$search%"."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

and ur another select statement

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from  basicinfo WHERE `name`='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 0):

Server version: 5.5.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
**$sql = mysql_query("select * from  staffreg WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' or description LIKE '%".$search."%' or keyword LIKE '%".$search."%'") or die(mysql_error());**

**$sql = mysql_query("select * from  search WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' or description LIKE '%".$search."%' ") or die(mysql_error());**
```

USE Mysql latest version install your system and all query you should write after print your browser. and run sql (PHPMYADMIN). GET result..